# return function inside with() block

Tags: r

How does `return()` in a `with()` block work?
Here is a test function

```r
test_func <- function(df, y) {
  with(df,
       if(x > 10){
         message('Inside step 1')
         return(1)
       }
  )
  message("After step 1")

  if(y > 10){
    message('In side step 2')
    return(2)
  }  
  message("After step 2")
}
```

- The function keeps going after `return(1)`.

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 11)
y <- 11
test_func(df, y)  ## result is 2
```

Output

```
Inside step 1
After step 1
In side step 2
[1] 2
```

- `return(1)` doesn't return to the `test_func()` rather than get out the `with()` block

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 11)
y <- 5
test_func(df, y) ## no result
```

Output

```
Inside step 1
After step 1
After step 2
```

Comment: Maybe missing the spirit of the question, but the workaround is to move `with` inside the `if`: `if(with(df, x > 10))`. If `with` is required for the return value, you can also put `with` inside `return` e.g. `return(with(df, 1))`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @IceCreamToucan

Comment: Interesting. `with(iris, return(1))` does not result in an error even though `return` is not used within a function.  Similarly for `local(return(1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main point here is that `return()` is designed to exit the current scope to the parent scope with a particular value. In the case of running

```
return("hello")
# Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

You get an error because we are calling this from the global environment and there is no parent scope you are jumping back to. Note that thanks to R's lazy evaluation, parameters passed to a function are usually evaluated in the environment where they were passed from. So in this example

```
f <- function(x) x
f(return("hello"))
# Error in f(return("hello")) : 
#   no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

So because we are actually passing in the `return()` call to the function from the global environment, that's where the return will be evaluated and will return the same error. But note that this is not what `with` does, instead it captures the commands you pass and re-runs them in a new environment. It's closer to something like this

```
f <- function(x) eval(substitute(x))
f(return("hello"))
# [1] "hello"
```

This `eval()` creates a new level of scope we can escape from, and because we aren't evaluating the parameter passed to the function directly, we are just running those commands in a different environment, the `return` is no longer evaluated in the global environment so there's no error. So the function we created is basically the same as calling

```
with(NULL, return("hello"))
# [1] "hello"
```

which is different from something like

```
print(return("hello"))
# no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

where the parameter is directly evaluated. So the different meanings of `return()` really are side effects of non-standard evaluation in this case.

When `return()` is used inside a `with()`, you are not returning from the function that you called `with()` from, but you are returning from the scope that `with()` created for you to run your command.

How to fix this particular problem is already addressed by the comments left by @IceCreamToucan. You just need to move the return outside of the `with()`.